# j_security_check form authentication with angular 4 application

Tags: angular, wildfly, j-security-check

We have a J2EE based application running on wildfly 8.1. We need to configure form authentication in web.xml for UI which is written in angular4. We have a angular4 app with LoginComponent which accepts j_username and j_password.

How to map angular 4's LoginComponent's LoginPage in web.xml for FormAuthentication

Comment: Hello, did you get any solution for this ??